# How to use DevExpress Logify with Postsharp 5.0 Logging along with Serilog

Tags: devexpress, postsharp, devexpress-wpf, logify

DevExpress Logify supports SeriLog and logs all fatal erros to its server. According to their document when ever serilog logs an error it will automatically trigger Logify as follows

```
 Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Seq("http://localhost:5341").MinimumLevel.Error()
            .WriteTo.Console(LogEventLevel.Error)
            .WriteTo.LogifyAlert()
            .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
            .CreateLogger();
```

its working fine when using Serilog but the moment I use postsharp the event is not logged.

```
  LoggingServices.DefaultBackend = new SerilogLoggingBackend();
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: `MinimumLevel.Error()` will apply globally here, not just to the Seq sink - is the PostSharp logger recording any events at this level? HTH.

Comment: Do you mean that the errors you're reporting manually using the Serilog API are not logged, or that the logging records added by PostSharp are not logged?

Comment: Hi, Gael Fraiteur, I have already created an issue with Logify Github repo. https://github.com/DevExpress/Logify.Alert.Clients/issues/1 when reporting manually with serilog it works fine. Only when using postsharp I find the issue.

Comment: @Noufal Aboobacker, please re-post an official answer here, if any

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the aforementioned [link](https://github.com/DevExpress/Logify.Alert.Clients/issues/1), currently, it is necessary to access the **LogifyAlert.Instance** property before creating **LoggerConfiguration** to initialize a Logify engine inside a plugin.

```
LogifyAlert client = LogifyAlert.Instance;
...
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration();
```